# iPadOS/iOS 13.4 Enterprise Apps crash

Tags: ios, swift, provisioning-profile, ipados, ios13.4

I have notice that my enterprise apps after update to iPadOS 13.4 crash (like when provisioning profile expires, but they are up to date) but seems like when user redownload ipa file from server and install it again everything works. What is even more strange it happens randomly not for all users. Does anybody know how i can prevent users from this crash on 13.4 version ? Its a iOS bug or i just forget to do something with my certificates/ code ?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: any ways to get the crash log

Comment: unfortunately device crash log is empty

Comment: i find this hard to believe that if there is a crash there is nothing in the crash log. Furthermore, if a enterprise app is crashing on download you need to check the certificates as well as your enterprise apple account to make sure everything is up to date. If your enterpirse dev account has expired or requires re-authentication.. apps will crash

Comment: Maybe i wrote it not clear, apps installed on device, after i update iOS to 13.4 are  crashing, to resolve it user need to redownload app. Well its true, i dig from all crash reports and there is none with today date when i reproduce crash. If it would be expired cert or account, user would be unable to download app. And i check it twice , everything is up to date. Also as i wrote it happens only on 13.4 version

Comment: It seems like crash is connected with changes in MDM system. For some reason my apps are not visible in MDM system for 13.4 platform, probably i need to compile .ipa files with new certificates, adding information like who will use app, how many users etc. I hope this will resolve my problem.